# Big O growth hierarchy?

Tags: big-o

I'm trying to figure out where `O(sqrt(n))` and `O(n2 log n)` fit in this growth hierarchy listed below. This chapter is so confusing and i'm lost on how to figure this out. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
O(1)
O(log log n)
O(log n)
O(log2 n)
O(n)
O(n log n)
O(n2)
O(n3)
O(2n)
O(n!)
```

Comment: Use a software that draws functions and look at the assymptote.

Comment: wolfram|alpha - y=1, y=log(x), y=x^2... you follow?

Comment: Have you graphed them? There are many examples [here](http://science.slc.edu/~jmarshall/courses/2002/spring/cs50/BigO/index.html).

Comment: By O(log2 n), you mean the base 2 logarithm, and by O(log n), you mean the common logarithm (base 10), correct? All logarithms are actually the same complexity class, no matter what the base, because they're all related by constant factors. This is unlike exponentials where each base *is* its own complexity class.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math/compsci and would be better suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

1. O(1)
2. O(log(log(n)))
3. O(log n)
4. O(log₂ n)
5. O(sqrt(n))   (due to sqrt(n) = n<sup>1/2</sup>)
6. O(n)
7. O(n log n)
8. O(n²)
9. O(n² log n) (n² + anything is larger than n². log n is smaller than n<sup>1+1</sup>)
10. O(n³)
11. O(2ⁿ)
12. O(n!)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the second one, O(n<sup>2</sup>*log<sub>10</sub>n), is easy to figure out. If you notice, n<sup>2</sup> has more weight than log<sub>10</sub>n as it grows exponentially whereas log will converge at the number of digits in the maximum number on the x-axis. So this equation will produce values larger than n<sup>2</sup> but less than n<sup>3</sup>.

Lastly, the first, O(sqrt(n)), log(n) < sqrt(n) for all n > 0. Here is the [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145739/prove-that-logn-o-sqrtn).

### Additional Information

Below is a figure that plots all 12 of the equations from left-to-right and top-to-bottom.

[image]

With the following code, I was able to plot all 12 functions.

```python
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure,plot,savefig,subplot,tight_layout,title,text
from numpy import linspace,log10,log2,sqrt
from scipy.misc import factorial

def plotEq(loc, lbl, n, eq):
    subplot(4,3,loc)
    plot(n,eq)
    text(60,.025,r'$\mu=100,\ \sigma=15$')
    title(lbl)

n = linspace(2,100,500)
figure()

plotEq(1, 'log10(log10(n))', n, log10(log10(n)))
plotEq(2, '1', n, n**0)
plotEq(3, 'log10(n)', n, log10(n))
plotEq(4, 'log2(n)', n, log2(n))
plotEq(5, 'sqrt(n)', n, sqrt(n)) # Here
plotEq(6, 'n', n, n)
plotEq(7, 'n*log10(n)', n, n*log10(n))
plotEq(8, 'n**2', n, n**2)
plotEq(9, '(n**2)*log10(n)', n, (n**2)*log10(n)) # Here
plotEq(10, 'n**3', n, n**3)
plotEq(11, '2**n', n, 2**n)
plotEq(12, 'n!', n, factorial(n))

tight_layout()
savefig("plot_subplots.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

> O(log<sup>2</sup> n) ⊂ **O(√n)** ⊂ O(n)

O(√n) is O(n<sup>½</sup>). This is faster than O(n) but slower any logarithmic function. Logarithms grow reaaaaaally slowly, slower than any positive power of n, even n<sup>0.01</sup>. It doesn't matter if you square the logarithm or even [raise it to the millionth power](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x**0.01+-+ln**1000000000+x+as+x+approaches+infinity).

> O(n<sup>2</sup>) ⊂ **O(n<sup>2</sup> log n)** ⊂ O(n<sup>3</sup>)

We know this because you can factor out the common n<sup>2</sup> and see that O(1) ⊂ O(log n) ⊂ O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Well, O(sqrt(n)) is definitely smaller than O(n), right?
Now let's think about whether O(log2 n) is greater or smaller than O(sqrt(n)).
If you are confused, just put a very big integer in n and calculate the values of them.
For example, when n is 1024, log2 n = 10, and sqrt(n) = 32. Therefore, O(log2 n) < O(sqrt(n))

```
O(log2 n) < O(sqrt(n)) < O(n)
```

Now, O(n^2 log n) is obviously smaller than O(n^3) since O(log n) < O(n).
Also, O(n^2 log n) is greater than O(n^2) since log n is greater than 1.

Therefore,

```
O(n^2) < O(n^2 log n) < O(n^3)
```